# How are treated disallowed windows® characters on a fat32 formated usb stick?

Tags: macos, usb, path, filenames, fat32

I don’t own a mac so I can’t tell about things like`?`or`:`in filenames…

I’m especially interested in the Dos/Windows® path separator :`\`. I know in Linux it is a legal character which can be used inside fat32 filenames *(Windows® will complain the volume is corrupt)*.
Does the same is true for osx ? Or does running`mkdir ..\\dirent`will create`dirent`in the parent directory *(still in the case of fat32 as I already know the behaviour on hfs)* ?

Of  Course I’m talking about the case where the volume is mounted through the Finder.
Depending on the answer, it might confirm the existence of a vulnerability in a popular source code management software…

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, and I had to find it out myself on my MacBook with operating system "OS X El Capitan". You have to differentiate between unallowed characters in the finder / applications using the finder (e. g. text editor) versus the command line.

First of all, the backslash "\" is like any normal character both in finder and the command line. So you can create a file or directory like A\B. Same is true for the question mark.

When it comes to the colon ":", then it becomes complicated. When you create a file named A:B at the command line, then it's created and displayed properly at the command line, but it gets displayed as A/B in the finder. And if you try to create a file containing a colon in finder, like C:D, then you get the error "The name C:D can't be used. Try using a name with fewer characters, or with no punctuation marks."

Creating a file or directory that begins with the dot "." can be done at the command line, no problem. But since these kind of files and directories are used for hidden files and directories, you cannot create them in finder. Instead you will get an error window telling "You can't use a name that begins with a dot ".", because these names are reserved for the system. Please choose another name."
If you execute the command

```
mkdir ..\\dirent
```

at the command line then this creates the hidden directory with the name

```
..\\dirent
```

in the current directory, so not a directory called `dirent` in the parent directory.

By the way: I tested this with a fat32 formatted usb stick, but even if I used an NTFS formatted external hard drive or the internal HFS+ formatted internal SSD drive it behaves the same.

If I look at all these files and directories (that I wrote on my MacBook to the USB stick) in Windows Explorer (with Windows 10) then both the backslash, the colon and the question mark are displayed differently than on the MacBook, each of them with the same special character which I cannot create on my keyboard nor can I copy and paste properly - pasting in this window here creates "" which doesn't look like the character displayed in Windows Explorer. In Windows Explorer it looks similar to the dot ".", but this dot is located somewhat above the regular dot, so vertically in the middle.

I hope I could help you somehow.

Comment: Ok : short answer : it uses the cygwin way by remapping characters on the fat32 volume *(backslash included)*. isn’t it ?

Comment: @Helmut: `:` is the underlying file path separator for HFS+ drives like OS X uses. It is impossible to create a file with a colon as part of the filename. (Actually, `:` is the only disallowed character on HFS+). When you created a file in Terminal named `A:B`, it in reality created a file named `A/B`, as evidenced by the Finder. What you're seeing in Terminal is seen through "POSIX eyes". POSIX uses a slash `/` as the file path separator, yet HFS+ allows slashes `/` in filenames, so how is POSIX to make sense of this? By "converting" the `/` in filenames to `:` for display.